# Syntax Error : replacing TYVAR with SEMICOLON CPN Tools

Tags: cpn-tools

## Syntax Error Image

[Syntax Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NaMv.png)


What is meant by TYVAR here and how can it be resolved such that there is error in parsing it?

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the above problem we use the **TILDE** ( ` or ~ ) symbol rather than ( ' ) this quotes symbol.